# How to improve an Expo Go app with firebase and local cache in Redux

Tags: caching

For learning purposes and fun, I created an Expo Go app with react-native for recipes. It has a firebase database and uses redux to manage state locally on each device. So far so good. A couple of friends are actually using the app encouraging me to improve it even further.

To get started, I decided to load all data on startup, after certain actions and if the users actively refreshes. This works, but for sure has many issues. I have no back-end server (other than the firebase database) which makes it easy for me to develop, but hard to keep the local cache valid. I recently introduced the feature to "like a recipe" and obviously if many users send a like at roughly the same time (or before refreshing their data), the latest "like" overrides the others. This results in data-loss. This is just one example where users may override data, because their local cache is not having recent changes made by others.

I am now wondering what would be a decent and straight forward to implement way to improve this user experience. Refreshing always before editing any database value is what comes to mind. However, cache invalidation is considered one of the hardest problems in software engineering.

Thinking further ahead, I would probably need a way to download/upload not the whole cache, but parts of it instead. Any suggestions how to continue? Should I read about cache invalidation? Is my issue likely generic? Or are there maybe already solutions for mobile apps with Expo/Firebase/Redux, because many people will have this issue?